# Is there a way to manually replace one disk in Microsoft Storage Spaces?

Tags: raid, data-recovery, storage-spaces

I got a microsoft storage spaces which using 4 disks and acting as RAID0, recently I found one of them failed.

I knew I should add a new disk into this space and kick the failed one out, but instead, I halt the win10 and pop the failed one out, mount it on a linux system, using ddrescue to copy the entire disk into a new disk.

Now I hoping when I replace the failed one with this new disk and boot the system, I can get the storage spaces works like before, but I'm afread I can losing the entire space, any suggentions ?

Comment: IMHO you lost already your data, restart from scratch and this time use at least one ressilaince. i use also storage spaces with raid zero configuration but i am aware about it, and only things that there are on, are data that can be easy re-downloaded...

Comment: Hello, welcome to ServerFault.com, where more junior sysadmins storage dreams come to be dashed across the unforgiving rocks of reality, only to be illuminated by wise old men sat in the lighthouse above scoffing about how they've seen all this a thousand times. Basically don't use R0, or R5/50 for that matter - stick to R1/10 or R6/60 and you'll be here less :)

Comment: [SOLVED] It works, I guess u really can cheat storage spaces with full disk clone

Answer (score 5):

Nope, all of your data is gone. You replace the disk that failed, you reconfigure your new RAID set as RAID10 now, and recover your original data from backup.